# Can I see the 10 candidates in the primary that would proceed to election phase?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-election

I up/down voted the candidates during the primary of the 2014 moderator elections. How can I see the 10 candidates that would proceed to the election phase if the election phase would start **right now**?

I understand that the ordering is random to not influence this initial voting unduly and that is good..
But now that I have voted I would like to see how things stand, and maybe switch a down- to an up-vote in order to make some candidate end up before some other candidate.

Two candidate might have different, low, preference for me, and I have down voted both, to give a better chance to the candidates that I prefer most. But if the less preferred candidate of those two has one vote more than the other I rather switch my vote to up for that other candidate.

You can of course copy and paste the names and scores in file and sort by score, and I already have a program that scrapes the page and does so automatically. But it would be nicer if there is some URL away from the page where you vote, where you can actually see the order of the candidates by votes' score.

If the data explorer has this data, I could write some query there, but the data there only gets update once a week, so that doesn't make much sense.

Of course this should be hosted on one of the stackoverflow sites, so there can be no doubt about the correctness of the data and/or the update rate.

---

For those who pinged me and asked, this is the crude scraper:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib2

name_next = False
vote_count = -1

candidates = []

for line in urllib2.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary'):
    if 'user-details' in line:
        name_next = True
        continue
    if 'vote-count-post' in line:
        vote_count = int(line.split('>', 1)[1].split('<', 1)[0])
    if name_next == True:
        name_next = False
        candidate = line.split('>', 1)[1].split('<', 1)[0]
        candidates.append((vote_count, candidate))

for idx, candidate in enumerate(sorted(candidates, reverse=True)):
    if idx == 10:
        print('--------------------------------')
    print("{0:>20}  {1}".format(candidate[1], candidate[0]))
```

Comment: You could use this user script: [StackExchange Election: Primary counter](http://stackapps.com/q/4548); it adds a table with all the candidates ordered by vote count, complete with a visible cut-off line.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I am asking for a feature request. It is better that something is provided by [so] and not by one of the candidates (I am not implying that JasonC would manipulate, it is just better to have a objective source for something like this)

Comment: @Anthon I agree that an SE hosted solution would be ideal. To that end check out poke's userscript that Martijn linked to, it just pulls the data off the page, using the page itself as the source. For now I'm going to convert my answer to a comment, as you tagged [tag:feature-request], not [tag:support]. A real answer would be a status tag. For accuracy comparisons you can compare the monitor's output to the current counts on the page; if you see any issues there please let me know! So now, as a separate comment in case these get cleaned up:

Comment: SE has no built-in functionality for this, but in addition to the great userscript that Martijn linked to in the above comment, I've also written a [live voting monitor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290346/2015-election-live-vote-monitor) web application that you can use to get that info as it happens.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this post on the grounds that, at least according to its tags, it is a feature request for SE to implement behavior that is similar to the behavior of existing third-party tools. I do not believe that the existence of tools that provide a similar functionality invalidates a feature request. If this was tagged as support or discussion I would feel otherwise. I also recommend that @Anthon either rephrase the post to more accurately reflect that it is a feature request (rather than asking "How do I...?"), or re-tag.

Comment: One, through BeautifulSoup parser https://gist.github.com/Avinash-Raj/b0edbd61c349cbeb8e20