# 2015 Election Live Vote Monitor

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

### Updated for the November 2015 election!

I wrote a [live election activity monitor](http://disorient.ddns.net/SOVoteMonitor/) which you can use to see the current status and watch the votes live; it shows the cutoff line for the final phase as well.

**Image below is sample only, counts and ranks are outdated and do not reflect the current votes. See the actual page for current stats.**

[image]

In the near future, I hope to say: We've actually been transfixed by it since the election began over in the [election chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94634/fall-2015-moderator-election-chat). Be warned, it can be addicting (If you were witness to the intensity in the first 24 hours, you understand; fortunately for us all the voting activity has calmed down now).

I had originally kept it private to the chat rooms to avoid hammering my poor web server with requests, but I think it will be OK. Please don't share the link outside of SO posts and such. While this post is obviously available to the public, I'd rather it didn't make it out to Twitter, etc.

The application is easy on SO. The server scrapes the election page for vote counts once every 5 seconds and caches them locally. The web page reads the server-cached data.

There's also a [version that attempts to look more like SO](http://disorient.ddns.net/SOVoteMonitor/?style=so), although I prefer the Geocities look myself.

[Source is on GitHub](https://github.com/JC3/SOVoteMonitor). Please don't make fun of it.

Enjoy!

Also, [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke) has a [really awesome user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/4548/stackexchange-election-primary-counter) that generates a static version of this table right in the stats page. Check it out!

Check out [Undo's live vote monitor](http://soprimaries.erwaysoftware.com/) as well!

---

[A more raw form of the data](http://disorient.ddns.net/SOVoteMonitor/raw), sorted by votes, is available for bots and such, or you can do ([thanks SecondRikudo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22703366#22703366)):

```
watch -cd -n5 "curl -s http://disorient.ddns.net/SOVoteMonitor/raw | column -ts '\"'"
```

I'd prefer you use the web interface instead of the raw output for general watching, however, as it's a bit less bandwidth.

If you find yourself motivated to create a new front-end, or have any other use, `/SOVoteMonitor/votes?t=c` and `/SOVoteMonitor/votes` serve JSON data; the former serves a list of candidates sorted by user ID (this will never change and should only be queried once), the latter serves the current vote counts in the same order as the candidate list. The `r` field in both is the current server application version.

The `e` field in `/votes?t=c` is the timestamp of the end of the primary elections.

The `s` field in `/votes` is the data serial number, updated by server when vote counts changed. If `s=<serial>` is specified to `/votes` you'll get a 304 if the data hasn't changed. This helps minimize bandwidth. If you don't want to deal with 304's, don't pass `s`. `s=0` is guaranteed to get a response.

The `w` field in `/votes`, if present, is an array of indexes into the original candidate info list of candidates who have withdrawn.

---

Change Log:

- Version 16: Updated URLs for November 2015 election. GitHub source still on 14.
- Version 14: Sloppily stop querying for updates after primaries end.
- Version 13: Candidates who have withdrawn are now indicated.
- Version 11: Added countdown timer! Also links to the no-longer-top-secret styles. Sorry about the momentary down time.
- Version 8b: Added SO-style styling but I kind of like the current version better; so if you add the top secret `style=so` parameter, [you'll get it](http://disorient.ddns.net/SOVoteMonitor/?style=so). Also try [`style=astro`](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3317125#3317125).
- Version 8: "Accum" saved in local storage across page refreshes (when supported), hopefully will no longer discourage folks to refresh page when update is made. Selected interval saved as well. Also no more new JSESSIONID cookies; it was a waste of bandwidth.
- Version 7: Add data versioning and 304 responses, add dropdown to select interval (thanks MichaelT for [suggestions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290346/2015-election-live-vote-monitor#comment177515_290346)). Also added "show debug info" at bottom.
- Version 6: Added election info links.

---

<sub>Yes, I am aware that the sort is unstable and tied candidates swap places. It's part of the excitement.</sub>

Comment: "Source is on GitHub." You guys, it's written in JSP.

Comment: @BoltClock They didn't want anyone to steal the code.

Comment: Thank you for this script I'm using it the last two days and it is great!

Comment: I haven't dug into too deeply - given you are fetching JSON, is it feasible to have the 'if-modified-since' header on the request to avoid fetches of data that just says the same thing as last time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I see the 10 candidates in the primary that would proceed to election phase?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290301/can-i-see-the-10-candidates-in-the-primary-that-would-proceed-to-election-phase)

Comment: @Anthon I decided to create a general post for this rather than leaving it in the answer there; since this is a bit broader scope than the feature request, and this post title is directly related to the application. Also this provides the opportunity for dedicated discussion. Personally, I would rather delete my answer there and leave this here. I left the answer there as a courtesy (I did edit it when I posted this to mention this post). :)

Comment: @Anthon it is better to close that question as a dup of this one I think.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm not necessarily convinced about that, either. Anthon's post is tagged [tag:feature-request] rather than [tag:support], so the presumption is that it's a request for SE to add a feature to the site itself. My application is somewhat incidental to that feature request. Slugster had brought the post to my attention and it seemed like a good place to mention the vote monitor that we'd already been using. What I *probably* should have done is mentioned it in a comment there which, actually, I am going to do.

Comment: @JasonC I tend to take a very broad view of duplicates on meta.  Although I see the point on the feature request vs this one.

Comment: @JasonC the other aspect of that (and the associated header) is that if there are any proxies between you and us that are shared between us (say, at a university or company), its even fewer requests that actually hit your server because the fetch can resolved at the cache.  Might also have a 'select polling rate' so those of us who aren't glued to the screen can select '2 minutes' rather than '5 seconds' (makes our own IT department that much happier).

Comment: @JasonC If two candidates are tied, it displays them in a random order?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes, the display order sort is done client side through JavaScripts `.sort()` and is keyed only on vote count, and depending on the browser, `.sort()` is unstable. So they jump around. It bugs me to no end, it was pointed out in chat yesterday, too. I *could* use e.g. user ID as the "tie breaker" for display order, but ... I think I'm just going to leave it for now and hope that all ties are eventually broken. If I fix it I'd need to do it completely, and have proper handling of ties (e.g. tied rank #'s, an accurate representation of who's above the cutoff line, etc.)

Comment: @MichaelT As it turns out, it seems getting predictable behavior with if-modified-since is tricky. Instead, I now have the server versioning the data and sending it, and the front-end adding its version as a get parameter. Server returns 304 if not modified. Less bytes than the request header anyways, and much more predictable, although I lose those intermediate proxy cache benefits - but current load is reasonable anyways. Also I've added a selector to the web page to configure the update rate and keep the surly IT guys at bay. Update just released. Thanks for the great suggestion.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the live monitor,   I will try it now on my dev Machine.

Comment: My intention is to use this for the next election, as well as expand it to cover other site elections. Currently this app still works and serves the purpose of showing vote counts; and acting as a hub for links, but obviously it's main use is done for now. Should I move this over to stackapps now that the primaries are over? It also seems inappropriate to continue updating the revision history in this meta post, even though I'm still making changes. I noticed a "no-repro" close vote; that could make sense for now. What should the fate of this post be?

Comment: Your link appears broken: "The requested resource (/SOVoteMonitor/) is not available."

Comment: Yes, this is from the last 2015 election. I'll be reviving it for this one as soon as I can!

Comment: @JasonC If you need a home for this, I'm happy to provide one.

Comment: Can you confirm that you'll have this up and running in two hours?

Comment: @Undo No. But maybe 6-8.

Comment: @JasonC Okay, that's fine. I'm racing to get a substitute up and running, don't worry about it

Comment: @Undo For the love of Gosling. Theoretically it's ready to go but I'm getting 403's from http://stackoverflow.com/election/7?tab=primary for some reason. I have 20 minutes to debug before this conference call.

Comment: @JasonC Possibly because it's not primary time yet.

Comment: @Undo No it works fine from a browser.

Comment: I'm not sure, then - possibly your server's IP is blocked for some reason?

Comment: @Undo Same IP as this machine.

Comment: @Undo Fixed; user-agent issue. There you go, guys. Table will be blank until primaries open.

Comment: @JasonC It seems to be showing 4 days in the countdown (`4:01:03:35`)?

Comment: @EdCottrell Yeah it parses it very naively from the right side of http://stackoverflow.com/election/7?tab=primary. Unless they rearranged things the countdown should become correct once the primaries begin.

Comment: @JasonC Cool. Thanks for doing this again.

Comment: It's alive!!!!!

Comment: Can't watch it on my work machine, but glad to see this works well on my phone! It looks like it's working great, Jason. Once again, good job.

Comment: @JasonC Will the red line break be moved once the election phase starts to reflect that three moderators will be elected?

Comment: @Trasiva No. I can't track anything during the election phase. The vote counts during that phase are private. So I wouldn't know where to put the red line. Can't tell which 3 it will be until it's over.

Comment: @JasonC That's a shame, but thanks for saving me the time of building this myself! That's what I love about the SO community, all sorts of neat little tools are already available without having to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Trasiva Nonsense. We wouldn't be proper programmers if we didn't constantly reinvent wheels. v.v

Comment: In the last election you ended just below that redline. It doesn't look like much has changed. Are you sure you are updating your own vote results correctly?

Comment: @rene In the last election I think there was a vote gap of about 5 votes between #8 - #11, I dropped to 11 roughly 2 seconds before the end. I'll conspire with Undo to fudge our counters' numbers for added suspense as the time gets closer. Then we can charge more for seats.

Comment: @rene Oh wait I get it. Yes I'm hard coded at 11. I told you my humor was broken.

Comment: @JasonC sounds like a nice scipt. How do you get your data? Directly from the webpage? Or with a query on a Database?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Directly from the page, [here](https://github.com/JC3/SOVoteMonitor/blob/master/src/sovotemon/MonitorContextListener.java#L133).