# Live Primary Tracker for the 2016 Election

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

In the spirit of [Jason C's tools of years past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290346/1849664), I've written and am running [a live monitor for this year's election:](https://soprimaries.charcoal-se.org/)

It should be fairly resilient to large amounts of traffic. Maybe don't get it on the front page of Reddit, but otherwise it shouldn't break.

### [soprimaries.charcoal-se.org](https://soprimaries.charcoal-se.org)

Additionally, I plan to produce [pretty graphs](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/94634?m=27006656#27006656) throughout the primary:

[image: pretty!]

I have (or will have) all of this data - vote counts for every candidate every ~5-10 seconds. What could one do with it? Is there any interest in a dump at the end of the primary?

Comment: You say "don't get it on the front page of reddit" almost like a challenge...

Comment: Maybe you can share it on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets)?

Comment: Is it possible to link the usernames to their election posts rather than their profiles?

Comment: Pink? Really? I'll never forgive you for this, Undo! _*Shakes fist*_

Comment: Sorry @Cerbrus, I didn't quite get the color right. Colors in charting libraries are hard, I was going for a slightly brighter pink.

Comment: I wanted a Pink/Purple/Gold dashed line...

Comment: Speaking to the comment regarding a dump at the end of the primary and would anyone be interested -- I would!

Comment: This should be a featured post!

Comment: So who's the top? There are 2 pairs of users that appear to have the same color in this graph. I see it's easier to tell in the site you're hosting (which is nice), but in a graph we'll need more colors.

Comment: @Mike The legend in the graph is ordered correctly, but it's also not live. [Here's a live version](//soprimaries.charcoal-se.org/vote_counts/graph), but it has a tendency to crash browsers.

Comment: I appreciate that. makes it much easier to see. In the image you posted above both of the duplicated colors were on top of each other so I wan't sure if that was a second line or if that was some kind of group or you just ran out of colors and had to repeat. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike Yep, that makes it a little more difficult to see what's happening. I'll through a new image up there.

Comment: It would be cool to see the voting rate over time. From the graph it appears to show that more people vote at certain times.