# Would others appreciate an option to hide votes when voting for SO elections?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-election

Basically I find the number of existing votes distracting/biasing. As I read through moderator candidates, after the first 4-5 I tend to read more attentively those with high votes. I'm aware I'm biased by the vote counts even though I try not to be.

This could create the outcome that candidates with early votes are more likely to get noticed and get further votes. I do appreciate the random nature of the lists in alleviating much of the potential bias already.

I'm not asking to make the number of votes hidden, only to have an option at the top to hide them for those desiring so, or a button to display votes for those desiring.

Regardless, at the next vote I'll simply `$('.vote-count-post').hide()` to fix it for myself.

Comment: The "Nomination" phase tab is still selectable, which has no votes and the candidates ordered by date.

Comment: Very much agreed. We might all want to believe we can rise above being influenced, but ultimate that number you see cannot be unseen.

Comment: I think that would be a great improvement. Gong back a forth from the Nomination tab is unwieldy and not a good option in my opinion. Having a simple way for everyone to click a button or toggle would be much better.

Comment: I opened a tab for each user and flipped between them reading the profiles then moving the tab sequence to reflect my vote order / closing tabs of those who didn't cut it.  That way I couldn't see the votes; only the activity.  Oddly the top voted person was bottom of my list, and the one at the top had no votes (whilst all others had hundreds).  Seeing that I almost changed my mind / spent a while considering; so this definitely has an influence.

Answer (score 15):

I'd be largely in favor of something like this.

The primary period of the moderator nominations always feels like a popularity contest, and the real thing we're trying to accomplish here is to see which ten candidates make it to the final round.  It doesn't make sense to see how far ahead other candidates are, although [it does make for some pretty interesting casual watching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337871/1079354), especially if something by a candidate greatly changes the minds of voters in large numbers.

Comment: I agree. In addition, as history has shown, the primary results do not really represent the final outcome anyway. E.g. in the [April 2016](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291017/216074) election, Jeremy Banks came in as 9th in the primary, but still got elected quickly after 5 eliminations. On the other hand, Jon Clements, who got in 3rd in the primary, was eliminated as the fourth in round 9. – So tl;dr, the voting results don’t really matter much apart from the “who gets into the final round” question.