# Live election results

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, moderator-election

[2019 Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11) ends tomorrow, I'm eagerly waiting to know who would be our next moderators ♦. Then the idea of *real-time election results* popped into my mind.

Clearly, people have thought about this earlier and some of them even had tried to build several tools for this,

- [2015 Election Live Vote Monitor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290346/2408342)
- [Live Primary Tracker for the 2016 Election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337871/2408342)

So my question is, why is this feature still unavailable?

Comment: because elections are a private matter and sharing actual vote outcome during the election will introduce a bias, just as it would in a normal democratic election. Having live election results will do a disservice to a fair election process. So this feature shouldn't exist, at all.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The tools you found tracked the *primaries* phase of the election, where the voting results on each candidate is public. The current election was being tracked at https://primaries.charcoal-se.org/, for example (that's the same system as the one in the 2016 elections post you found, by Undo), all that the tool did was [scrape the elections page repeatedly](https://github.com/Undo1/PrimaryMonitor/blob/master/app/helpers/vote_counts_helper.rb) to track changes in the public data.

We are now in the last phase of the election, and the voting is **private**. There is nothing *to* track. The results will be announced shortly after voting closes.

Note that the voting in the last phase will never be made public during elections, you should be making up your mind about the candidates without being biased by live vote counts. Moreover, the way [Meek STV voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_single_transferable_votes#Meek) works doesn't really lend itself for 'live' results, as calculating the candidate ranking is a bit more complex than a [first-past-the-post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-past-the-post_voting) voting system. How you use your 2nd and 3rd candidate votes matters!

Comment: Is the URL being dead intentional?

Comment: @Script47: you'd have to ask Undo, who maintained the site. But probably, yes.

Comment: Note that Undo did post a data dump with all the data points used for that site [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/primaries.charcoal-se.org/primaries19.sql). You can reconstruct the graphs and run your own analyses on it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Furthermore, can mods see live results before the voting ends?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala: no, moderators can't see any more than you can.

Comment: @Roshana even if they could... What would it change? If we users can't... A mod won't risk his diamond in showing it to us ...